# use jooq in a project that already uses jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jooq

I have a spring boot project that uses jpa with hibernate and spring data to access database.
I have a many to many mapping between products and their locations (on shelves).
The product entity has a collection of shelves and vice versa.
I initially didn't need to return the locations to the client so i added @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) to the locations field in the product entity.
Now I need to send it so i removed the write_only and noticed my endpoint slowed down (from 75 ms to 450 ms loading time).
Thinking about solutions to optimize I decided to try making a similar request with jooq and it's much faster ( ~ 90 ms).
I used the multiset functionnality of jooq and converters to fetch into a new product dto that has a collection of locations.
I find this way of doing it perfect and I don't get the problem I had with jpa that product has locations, each locations has products and products has locations infinitely.

Here is the example I used : [jooq multiset and converters](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/jOOQ-Masterclass/blob/410b7c63c5b018a6f6ae40285de12d2c591d4a9f/Chapter08/PostgreSQL/Maven/Multiset/NestedMultiset/src/main/java/com/classicmodels/repository/ClassicModelsRepository.java#L79)

The problem is I am not 100% sure that it's ok to use jooq for this specific endpoint and continue using jpa for the rest of my app.
I am afraid the data fetched with jooq will not always be coherent with data handled by jpa because for some reasons I don't fully understand but i think it's related to flush modes, the changes made from hibernate are not automatically sent to the database.

Here is an article I found on how to use jooq and jpa in the same app [jooq with hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-jooq-a-match-made-in-heaven/) : the solution is to make the jooq queries by calling em.createNativeQuery

But this prevents me from using the powerfull jooq converters to map the query result directly to dto even with multisets nested collections.

Is it really necessary to use the entity manager for all requests to keep data coherent ? I would like to understand enough jpa so that the answer to these kind of questions will become clear. For example is there a problem using jdbc template and jpa in the same app without any preparation ?

Comment: Don't know who downvoted that looks like a legitimate question, 
apart from you link see:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.18/manual/sql-execution/alternative-execution-models/using-jooq-with-jpa/

it should be ok as long as you use the same connection pool(HikariCP for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is I am not 100% sure that it's ok to use jooq for this specific endpoint and continue using jpa for the rest of my app.

It's totally OK.

> the solution is to make the jooq queries by calling `em.createNativeQuery()`

It's not necessary to use `em.createNativeQuery()`.

If you really want to reuse the `Connection`/`Transaction` that Hibernate is using, you could use `Session.doWork()` or `Session.doReturningWork()`. (You would need to cast the `EntityManager` to `Session`.)

But even this is not necessary. Relational databases are meant to serve many different clients in a distributed system at the same time. You are not supposed to have to force your access to the database through one particular technology.

> Is it really necessary to use the entity manager for all requests to keep data coherent?

No. Absolutely not. That would go against *everything* that relational databases are about. *Of course* Hibernate would never force you to do that.

> For example is there a problem using jdbc template and jpa in the same app without any preparation?

Definitely not. That's completely fine.

There's just one thing you need to be careful about: if you use JPA and direct JDBC together in *a single unit of work*, you need to make sure that the work is happening inside a single transaction.

I'm not a Spring user but I'm sure Spring will take care of this detail for you.